# When asking a new question, if a user is logged out (but has an account), indicate prominently that they are LOGGED OUT

Tags: feature-request, login, logout

Stack does a great job of letting unregistered users ask questions, however, I sometimes find myself asking questions anonymously by mistake.

This is *mostly* due to being **logged in** on one site (ex: stackoverflow) and then asking a question on another site (ex: serverfault) ***without remembering to login***.

I believe a solution is to check if the user has ever logged in (through cookies) and display some PROMINENT TEXT to that user if they are logged out and trying to ask a new question.

Comment: I don't understand your feature request. Do you mean persistent cookies? For how long? If a user is logged out, well, he's *logged out*. Stack Exchange sites already log you in automagically if you're logged in another site, so what would this feature add except additional annoyance for people who genuinely *want* to browse the sites while logged out?

Comment: You actually get logged out?  SO doesn't log me out for, like, ever.  And even a particular site that i've been away from for too long recognizes me and is like "hey, i logged you back in.  You're welcome."  If a browser doesn't have/provide info that would enable that re-logging-in, how is a site going to recognize them anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well.. the fact that the login options appears between your question box and the submit button is a pretty good sign in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: I suppose this is a good enough indicator -- but it's easily skipped when I am asking a question and then looking for that post button. I just get the impression that others might have the same issue I've had. No big deal :)